# Unity make a function work for a specific time period

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

The player goes up when space bar is pressed and falls down if it is released. When the player collides with something, the controls change(player normally goes up and when you press space bar, it goes down). My code below do these works. However it should return the normal controls after 10 seconds(or after 5 scores. there is a score counter in another script however when I want to implement it, unity freezes). Right now, my code does not return the normal controls never.
Here is my code:

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Threading;
public class flying : MonoBehaviour
{
   public float gravity;
   public Rigidbody2D rb;
   public Vector2 startPos;
   public static flying Instance{get; private set;}
    public void start() {
       Instance=this;
       startPos=transform.position;
       rb=GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
       gravity=rb.gravityScale;
       }
   public void Update(){
        Vector2 vel=rb.velocity;
        float ang = Mathf.Atan2(vel.y,10)*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,0,ang));
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
        rb.AddForce(Vector2.up*gravity*Time.deltaTime*2000f);
    }
}
   void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){
       if(col.tag=="hellium"){
       StartCoroutine(Wait(10,col));

                Vector2 vel=rb.velocity;
                float ang = Mathf.Atan2(vel.y,10)*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,0,ang));
                if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
                rb.AddForce(Vector2.up*gravity*Time.deltaTime*2000f);
                }


       }
   }

        private IEnumerator Wait(float waitTime,Collider2D col)
    {         if(col.tag=="hellium"){

                rb.gravityScale*=-1;
                gravity=-gravity;
                Vector2 vel=rb.velocity;
                float ang = Mathf.Atan2(vel.y,10)*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
                transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,0,ang));
                if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
                rb.AddForce(Vector2.up*gravity*Time.deltaTime*2000f);

        }
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        print("Coroutine ended: " + Time.time + " seconds");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Coroutine.html)

```
private IEnumerator Wait(float waitTime)
    {
        //things that you write in OnTriggerEnter2D
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);
        print("Coroutine ended: " + Time.time + " seconds");
    }
```

then use like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col){
         StartCoroutine("Wait");
         //return things to normal again.
        }
```

Comment: It writes Coroutine ended in console after 10 seconds but the controls does not change

Comment: //return things to normal again How did you implemented this part ?

Comment: I multiplied gravityscale with -1 again

Comment: I edited my code  using your way. Now it changes the moving direction every time it collides with the hellium object

Comment: Okay now you can add a boolean to check whether it is already started or not. If it started already do nothing else start the process.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing with gravity here, you probably don't need the second line.

```
rb.gravityScale*=-1;
gravity=-gravity;
```

add this to normalize (if you remove a line from the on trigger enter remove it from the ontriggerexit)

```
void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D Col) {

    rb.gravityScale*=-1;
    gravity=-gravity;

}
```

as per why your counter is not working you need to show us the code for that and the error message

also remove this from OnTriggerEnter2D, you don't need it here, just where you have it in update

```
Vector2 vel=rb.velocity;
float ang = Mathf.Atan2(vel.y,10)*Mathf.Rad2Deg;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0,0,ang));
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space)){
rb.AddForce(Vector2.up*gravity*Time.deltaTime*2000f);
```